# i cant change Execution Policy on windows powershell

Tags: python, windows, powershell, pycharm

[powershell image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYwgs.png)
hi, i am trying to change the execution policy on powershell to be able to use pycharm since it gives me error otherwise, but when i try to do that, after i type "Y" or "A" and press enter it doesnt do anything at all.
[pycharm error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFqvq.png)

i tried to run powershell as administrator, copied the commands from websites to change the execution policy, it did nothing for me.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Default -Scope CurrentUser

Execution Policy Change
The execution policy helps protect you from scripts that you do not trust. Changing the execution policy might expose
you to the security risks described in the about_Execution_Policies help topic at
https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170. Do you want to change the execution policy?
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "N"): Y
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Default` [execution policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Execution_Policies) on *desktop* editions of Windows - `Restricted` - is precisely the one that *prevents* execution of script files.

You need to pick a policy that *allows* script execution, `RemoteSigned` being a good compromise (it allows execution of script files *except* those downloaded from websites via a browser):

```bash
# -Force skips the confirmation prompt.
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser -Force
```

This uses the [`Set-ExecutionPolicy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-executionpolicy) cmdlet to *persistently* configure the execution policy for *your* user account (takes effect immediately). `-Force` skips the confirmation prompt.

Note:

- For *machine-wide* configuration, use `-Scope AllUsers` - however, this requires *elevation* (run as admin)
- If GPOs (Group Policy Objects) control the execution policy on your machine, you can *not* use `Set-ExecutionPolicy` to override it.
- For more information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71564847/45375).