# SQL Server job can't run PowerShell because "scripts execution disabled"

Tags: sql-server, powershell, executionpolicy

I upgraded a Windows Server 2012 to 2019, but kept the SQL Server (110)

My sql agent jobs stopped working, the ones using PowerShell commands.

I get the error message

```
A job step received an error at line 1 in a PowerShell script. 
The corresponding line is 'import-module SQLPS  -DisableNameChecking'. 
Correct the script and reschedule the job. 
The error information returned by PowerShell is: 
'File C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\PowerShell\Modules\SQLPS\Sqlps.ps1 
cannot be loaded because the execution of scripts is disabled on this system. 
Please see "get-help about_signing" for more details.
```

The Sqlps.ps1 IS signed with a valid signature, and I even temporarily tried to `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted` , but that didn't help either. (All suggested by chatgpt ;-) )

My script should download a file from an url and place it in c:\tmp

EDIT:
Solved, I set the script execution policy to  "Allow local scripts and remote signed scripts" in group policy for computer; it was pereviously "Not Configured"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PowerShell says "execution of scripts is disabled on this system."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037939/powershell-says-execution-of-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If the effective [execution policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Execution_Policies) is `Restricted`, even *signed* scripts won't help you.
- What matters is what the effective execution policy is for the user identity that your services / scheduled tasks run as, which you can control as follows:

  - *Ad hoc*, in a given [PowerShell *CLI*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) call (`powershell.exe [-Command] ...` / `powershell.exe -File ...`), precede the (possibly implied) `-Command` / `-File` parameter with an `-ExecutionPolicy` argument, e.g. - if you fully trust the script (eventually) getting invoked - `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass`
  - *Persistently*, via a *machine-wide* execution policy (requires *elevation* (administrative privileges)):

    - Via [`Set-ExecutionPolicy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-executionpolicy) `-Scope AllUsers`
    - Via [GPO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_Policy) policies (which *override* persistent `Set-ExecutionPolicy` configurations).

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71564847/45375) for additional information.