# How to perform curl with commands on Windows 10,11 in CLI or Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, curl, invoke-webrequest

Want to find equivalent of this under Linux in Bash

```
sh <(curl https://sample.com/cli.sh)
```

in Windows CLI or Powershell

I know curl comes installed in Windows. How can I achieve it?

Some people will say it is insecure. Also I will have a cli.ps1 with Windows Powershell.

Comment: What can be insecure is piping a script directly to the shell like you're doing.. anyway, on windows you can use `Invoke-WebRequest`

Comment: Will this work: Run powershell.exe
```
$cli = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://sample.com/cli.ps1
$cli.RawContent > cli.ps1
cli.ps1```

Comment: Please remove the edit from the question and add an answer

Answer (score 5):

To offer **more concise alternatives** to [your own effective solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75865934/45375) - also assumes execution *from PowerShell*; the **usual caveats about directly executing code downloaded from the web apply**:<sup>[1]</sup>

```bash
powershell { iex (irm https://sample.com/cli.ps1) }
```

There are edge cases where the above malfunctions (see below); use the following **robust form** then, which also **makes it easy to pass *arguments*** to the script:

```bash
# More robust:
# Optionally pass arguments before the closing "}"
powershell { & ([scriptblock]::Create((irm https://sample.com/cli.ps1))) }
```

***Assuming you know that the script contains no `exit` statements*** (which would exit *your whole session*), you can even use ***in-process* execution** (as your solution via an aux. file does), as follows:

```bash
# Note: Execution via & { ... } prevents iex (Invoke-Expression) from
#       effectively dot-sourcing the code, i.e. from running it
#       directly in the calling scope, which can have unwanted side effects.
iex "& { $(irm https://sample.com/cli.ps1) }"

# More robust:
& ([scriptblock]::Create((irm https://sample.com/cli.ps1)))
```

In-process execution isn't just faster, it also enables a script to directly modify the current session's environment variables, and maintains full type fidelity with respect to the script's output objects, if any.
If the script *does* have `exit` statements, downloading to a (temporary) *file* first - as in your solution - is necessary, though the proposed future enhancement discussed below would make that unnecessary.

Note:

- `irm` is a built-in alias of the [`Invoke-RestMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod) cmdlet - see the next section for details.
- `iex` is a built-in alias of the [`Invoke-Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression) cmdlet.

  - Note that while `Invoke-Expression` is [generally to be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51252636/45375), here it enables execution of source code without the need for an aux. script *file* (`.ps1`).
  - `[scriptblock]::Create($sourceCodeString)` is a way to parse source code into a [*script block*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (whose literal form is `{ ... }`), i.e. a reusable unit of code that can be invoked *on demand* later, using either `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-) or `.`, the [dot-sourcing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#dot-sourcing-operator-).
    Its use bypasses the following `Invoke-Expression` bugs, present up to at least PowerShell 7.3.3.:

    - [GitHub issue #8815](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8815).
    - [GitHub issue #8778](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8778).
- Since no script *file* is involved in the above commands, the effective [execution policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Execution_Policies) does *not* apply.
  As an aside: If it did:

  - you could override it *for a given [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) call* with `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass`
  - you could set it *persistently*, using [`Set-ExecutionPolicy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-executionpolicy), as in your own answer - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71564847/45375) for background information.
- *Potential future enhancement*:

  - [GitHub issue #5909](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5909#issuecomment-461192202) discusses enhancing the [`Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command) cmdlet to robustly support execution of scripts directly from the web, based on an `Invoke-WebRequest` call as pipeline input.
  - If this were implemented, a robust, in-process invocation would look like this (using the built-in aliases `iwr` and `icm` alias of `Invoke-WebRequest` and `Invoke-Command`, respectively):

    ```bash
    # WISHFUL THINKING as of PowerShell 7.3.3
    # Append -- arg1 ... to pass arguments.
    iwr https://sample.com/cli | icm
    ```

---

##### `curl` vs. `curl.exe` vs. `Invoke-WebRequest` vs. `Invoke-RestMethod`:

- `curl.exe` indeed comes with recent versions of Windows.
- To call it from *Windows PowerShell*, be sure to call it *as `curl.exe`*, i.e. *with* the `.exe` extension.

  - In Windows PowerShell, `curl` - *without* the `.exe` part - is an *alias* of the [`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest) cmdlet, which is PowerShell's *analog* to `curl.exe`, albeit with very different syntax.
    Fortunately, this alias was removed from [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md).
    However, a built-in, PowerShell-idiomatic alias that can be used in *both* PowerShell editions to refer to `Invoke-WebRequest` is `iwr`.
- The related [`Invoke-RestMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod) cmdlet - whose built-in alias is `irm` - can be used in lieu of `Invoke-WebRequest` in cases where you only care about the response's *data*, not also about a rich response-information object *wrapping* the data.

  - Note: Plain-text data - such as a script's source code in your case - is returned as-is, but for XML- and JSON-based data `Invoke-RestMethod` conveniently parses the data into an XML DOM in the form of an `[xml]` ([`System.Xml.XmlDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlDocument)) instance and a custom-object graph ([`[pscustomobject]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_PSCustomObject)), respectively.

---

<sup>[1] Only do this if you either fully control or implicitly trust the contents of the script, so as to prevent potentially malicious code from executing.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser
$cli = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://server.com/cli-win.txt
$cli.Content > cli.ps1
./cli.ps1
```