# Run a .bat file from remote server in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, batch-file

For Python, I can run a remote script locally by the following command in PowerShell

```
(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://foo.bar.dev/script.py -UseBasicParsing).Content | python -
```

Can I do the same thing for a `.bat` file? Like

```
(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://foo.bar.dev/script.bat -UseBasicParsing).Content | pwsh -
```

Comment: You could just get the content of the file, save it to a bat file in %temp% or something then run the file with start-process?
Or if you used powershell instead, you could use it directly as base64 like:
`# To use the -EncodedCommand parameter:
    $command = 'dir "c:\program files" '
    $bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($command)
    $encodedCommand = [Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)
    powershell.exe -encodedCommand $encodedCommand`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Batch files (`.bat` and `.cmd`) are interpreted by *`cmd.exe`*, the legacy command processor ("Command Prompt"), not by *PowerShell*.

You therefore ***cannot* pipe the contents of a batch file directly to a PowerShell CLI** ([`pwsh.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) for [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)) , ([`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) for *Windows PowerShell*).

While you *can* pipe directly to `cmd.exe`, doing so has *severe limitations* and *may or may not* work as intended, depending on the content of the batch file - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39948297/45375).

Thus, you'll have to **save the downloaded batch-file content to a (temporary) file and execute it from there**, which PowerShell can help you automate:

```bash
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://foo.bar.dev/script.bat -UseBasicParsing |
  ForEach-Object { 
      $tmpBatchFile = "$env:TEMP\~{0}_{1}.cmd" -f $PID, ([datetime]::Now.ToString('o') -replace '\D')
      Set-Content -Encoding OEM $tmpBatchFile -Value $_
      & $tmpBatchFile # Execute
      Remove-Item $tmpBatchFile
  }
```

Note:

- [`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest) was replaced with [`Invoke-RestMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod), which directly returns the data of interest and parses it, if appropriate; in the case of plain-text output, it is passed through as-is, as multiline text (after decoding into a .NET string).
- It would be easy to create a *function wrapper*:

  - Precede the body of the `ForEach-Object` statement with
    `function Invoke-AsBatchFile`, for instance, to define a function by that name.
  - Replace `$_` in the body with `$input`
  - You can then use that function in the pipeline:

    ```bash
    Invoke-RestMethod ... | Invoke-AsBatchFile
    ```

---

Note:

- If you were to **download the content of *PowerShell scripts* (`*.ps1`)**, you would **execute it via `[scriptblock]::Create()`** (as the more robust alternative to `Invoke-Expression` (`iex`)), which has the added advantage of being able to run *in-process* - but only *if the script code doesn't contain `exit` statements*. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75867014/45375) for details.