# Cannot compile a ts file

Tags: typescript, powershell, terminal

So when i typed `tsc index.ts` into terminal to compile my file it only responded with:

```
tsc.ps1 cannot be loaded. tsc.ps1 is not digitally signed. You cannot run this script on the current system.
```

I tried some commands on powershell while running it as admin and none of them worked so i turned here.

Comment: You already tried `Set-ExecutionPolicy`? Just checking before I go into further detail (details I wouldn't recommend).

Comment: The implication is that the effective PowerShell script-execution policy requires your script to be _signed_ (or possibly that your script's signature is invalid). Your options are to either ensure that your script is [signed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Signing) or to [change your execution policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Execution_Policies) (e.g. `Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser RemoteSigned`) - [brief overview](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71564847/45375).