# Why i can't change the policy from restricted to remote signed?

Tags: powershell, executionpolicy

[image]

I hade a problem with 'touch' command , so someone tolled me that i should change the policy (in PowerShell) so I can run the script in vs code ,but the problem is that i couldn't change the policy from restricted to remote signed .

Comment: So, what happens when you follow the advice given in the error message?

Answer (score 2):

As the error message implies, your command requires *elevation*, i.e. must be run *with administrative privileges*.

The reason is that [`Set-ExecutionPolicy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-executionpolicy) defaults to the `LocalMachine` `-Scope` value, which - due to making changes at the *machine* level, i.e. for *all* users - requires elevation.

Therefore, you have two options:

- *Either*: Run your `Set-ExecutionPolicy` call from an elevated session:

  - Note:

    - To launch an elevated session, you either need to be a member of the Administrators group yourself, or you need an administrator to provide their credentials when prompted.
  - *Interactively*, you can create an elevated session by right-clicking on the PowerShell icon in the Start Menu or taskbar and selecting `Run as Administrator`
  - *Programmatically*, you can run the following from a (non-elevated) session (still requires interactive confirmation / authorization for elevation):

    ```
    Start-Process -Verb RunAs (Get-Process -Id $PID).Path '-Command Set-ExecutionPolicy -Force RemoteSigned'
    ```
- *Or*: Run the `Set-ExecutionPolicy` with `-Scope CurrentUser`, in which case elevation is *not* required:

  - Note:

    - As the scope name implies, this only persistently changes the [execution policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Execution_Policies) for the *current user*.
  - Run the following:

    ```
    Set-ExecutionPolicy -Force -Scope CurrentUser RemoteSigned
    ```

Note: `-Force` in the commands above suppresses the confirmation prompt that `Set-ExecutionPolic` presents by default.

---

For a comprehensive overview of PowerShell's execution policies, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71564847/45375).