# PowerShell error. Nuget Packed Console not working

Tags: c#, powershell, console, nuget-package, nuget-console

I started getting this error after I accidentally deleted the profile.ps1 file from the system files. I get this error when opening the console. what can I do to resolve the error?

[image]

Comment: Are you able to restore the file?

Comment: Please post text as _text_, rather than as an image.

Comment: I also get this error after restoring the file.

& : File C:\Users\Erkan KESEMEN\Desktop\NetDesign\NetDesign\packages\EntityFramework.6.4.4\tools\init.ps1 cannot be loaded because its operation is blocked by software restriction policies, such as those created by using Group Policy.
At line:1 char:45
+ ... rgs+=$_}; & 'C:\Users\Erkan KESEMEN\Desktop\NetDesign\NetDesign\packa ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess

Comment: I would try running a repair on Visual Studio, see if that sorts it.

Comment: @gunr2171 EntityFramework.6.4.4\tools\init.ps1 cannot be loaded because its operation is blocked by software restriction policies, such as those created by using Group Policy.
At line:1 char:45

Comment: You do not have permission to write to the Program Files Folder.  Only Admin have the permission.  When running the PS1 extension you need Admin permission.  Try running the PS1 by first right click the PS shortcut and select Run As Admin.

Comment: @jdweng unfortunately not

Comment: Change the PowerShell [execution policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Execution_Policies) to ensure that at least local execution of scripts is permitted - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71564847/45375)