# Vue not showing version?

Tags: vue.js, loaded

vue : File C:\Users\csarv\AppData\Roaming\npm\vue.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system.
For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1

- vue --version
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
  ```

vue --version       after installing vue js from npm

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037939/powershell-says-execution-of-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PowerShell says "execution of scripts is disabled on this system."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037939/powershell-says-execution-of-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have Vue.js installed globally on your system using npm or yarn before running the above commands. If you haven't installed Vue.js yet, you can do so by running the following command:

```
npm install -g @vue/cli
```

then you can use the vue --version command to check the installed version.

If you didn't installed globally then you can check vue version from package.json