# What is another way to run the file(Express.js)?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, express, node-modules, mern

PS C:\Users\Mani Kamaraj\Desktop\Expressjs> nodemon Express.js
nodemon : File C:\Users\Mani Kamaraj\AppData\Roaming\npm\nodemon.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For
more information, see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1

- nodemon Express.js
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
  ```

To run the Express.js file and before i already install the nodemon in my package "npm install -g nodemon" then after "nodemon Express.js"

PS C:\Users\Mani Kamaraj\Desktop\Expressjs> nodemon Express.js
nodemon : File C:\Users\Mani Kamaraj\AppData\Roaming\npm\nodemon.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For
more information, see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1

- nodemon Express.js
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
  ```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PowerShell says "execution of scripts is disabled on this system."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037939/powershell-says-execution-of-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system)