# block internet access with Test Complete

Tags: testing, testcomplete

Are there any way, to prevent the internet access of the tester application under the test whit Test Complete? I'd like to test the application's reaction of the lost of the internet connection, but I have to perform this whith a CI tool, which means the Test Complete have to block and unblock to connection.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using WMI directly from a script (see [Working With WMI Objects in Scripts](http://smartbear.com/viewarticle/87406/)) or by executing a PowerShell script (see [Running PowerShell Scripts From TestComplete](http://smartbear.com/viewarticle/86333/)).

For example, see this question to get a sample PS script:

[Command/Powershell script to reset a network adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207283/command-powershell-script-to-reset-a-network-adapter)